# xUnit 1.9.2 and .Net 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, xunit, xunit.net

I am trying to implement xUnit for C# testing but am running into a strange error.

I can run the unit tests in VisualStudio (2013) but when I try to run the same tests using the GUI or console I get the error:

```
xUnit.net console test runner (32-bit .NET 2.0.50727.5472)
Copyright (C) 2013 Outercurve Foundation.

Could not load file or assembly '[...]' or one of its dependencies.
This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded
runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

My project is using .net 4.0 and it appears xUnit is using 2.0.

I found a couple of posts [here](http://www.counsellingbyabhi.com/2013/02/using-xunitnet-with-net-40.html) and [here](http://usingimho.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/xunit-and-net-4-0/), among others, saying you can edit the config file but this didn't work for me.  Both of these posts are a couple years old and they don't even agree with each other.  One says the entry should be 'supportedRuntime' while the other is 'requiredRuntime'.  Neither of them work for me, however.

I also thought about downloading the source and compiling it using 4.0 but according to the web site it requires VS 2010.

Running the tests within the IDE is great but I also need to use the console runner in order to implement automated tests on our build machine.  Is there a way to get this to work?  Or is xUnit no longer being maintained?

I also found [another post](http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9683) where the issue was supposedly fixed back in 2010. Maybe this is a regression failure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks, Mark.  But I have since found there is a separate xunit.console.clr4.exe executable for .net 4.0.

Maybe I'm bitter after wasting 1/2 day on this but there is no mention of this on the xUnit web site.  In fact the site only talks about running the tests with VS.  I found reference to the console runner on blog sites.

Starting to wonder about xUnit, maybe I should look at nUnit.  It appears to at least have documentation.

Comment: Mark, can you accept this answer, please, so it doesn't show in the list?

Comment: There is also a separate xunit.gui.clr4.exe, though I didn't know that until I read this answer.

Answer (score 0):

On this page an unofficial build of the xunit runner is compiled with .net4 support - https://composure.codeplex.com/

I do not know if the xunit project is discontinued, the codeplex site still shows some activity in the git commit log but who knows...